# Find a relation between $A$ and $B$?(2)

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Let $2^a+3^b<4$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Q: Find a relation between $A$ and $B$ ?

$$A=2^{a+1}+3^{b+1}, B=2^a+3^b$$

Comment: Perhaps $2B<A<3B$?

Comment: Are you in the need of exact relation between $A,B$ or any inequality other inequality relation may do?

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{a + 1} + 3^{b + 1} = 2^{a}\cdot 2 + 3^{b} \cdot 3 = 2(2^a + \frac{3}{2} 3^b) > 2(2^a + 3^b)$$